# Python replication of Java web applic?

Tags: data-visualization, python, java, statistics, simulation

Can this Java web applic be replicated in Python and/or related toolkit (e.g., AI-Labs's Orange)?:

http://www.xjtek.com/anylogic/demo_models/38/

Comment: This question looks more appropriate for SO.  That application appears to be a simulation; it's not really data visualization, nor does it seem to have anything to do with statistics or data analysis.

Comment: "..anything to do with statistics or data analysis?"  The underlying statistics are using a bass diffusion model & agent based (swarm) techniques.  The visualization, provided within the link, summarizes those processes quite concisely.

Comment: @optimizerx Did you look at the [SimPy](http://simpy.sourceforge.net/) Simulation Package?

Comment: Not a real answer, but if it already exists in Java, why the need to replicate it in Python?

Comment: Yes, of course it can. Anything is possible. That doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: They're both Turing complete languages so yes you can.

Answer (score 1):

Check out  [GarlicSim](http://garlicsim.org/) as well.